# i can`t see the initial boot screen in booting

Tags: bios

I have  a rtx build with rtx 3060  and motherboard b660 a pro MSI.
I am connecting my screen with HDMI  port.

I have a problem now  that I cannot access BIOS  as I can't see the the initial boot screen and I can't display  it,  and it boots directly to Windows  even when I press the DEL button.

It seems that it accesses the BIOS but my monitor can't display anything in BIOS mode. I tried another monitor, still the same. Hope  anyone can help me with that issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I see this a fair bit:   Start up and get running.  Now, Restart.  This slows down the start up and allows you to press repeatedly F1 or whatever, or, follow what is on the screen. Works on a fast computer.

You also may need disable Fast Start.  Control Panel, Power Options, Sleep buttons and lid options:   Turn Off Fast Start.  Need to be Admin.

Assuming otherwise your computer is working properly, the above works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **DP** port, I have the same problem after I upgraded my monitor (to Benq ex2780q),

it doesn't show bios via HDMI it starts showing only when Windows login screen appears